# Cannot install alsa-driver, INCLUDE_VERSION_H cannot be found

Tags: drivers, kernel, alsa

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I want to upgrade my drivers as there is some problem with HDMI output. I tried to compile the alsa-driver package I downloaded from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/alsa-driver). Here's the output when I run `./configure`:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for current directory... /home/dnaik/Miscellaneous/alsa-driver-1.0.25+dfsg
checking cross compile... 
checking for directory with ALSA kernel sources... /home/dnaik/Miscellaneous/alsa-driver-1.0.25+dfsg/alsa-kernel
checking for directory with kernel source... /lib/modules/5.8.0-63-generic/build
checking for directory with kernel build... /lib/modules/5.8.0-63-generic/build
checking for kernel linux/version.h ... no
The file /lib/modules/5.8.0-63-generic/build/include/INCLUDE_VERSION_H does not exist.
Please install the package with full kernel sources for your distribution
or use --with-kernel=dir option to specify another directory with kernel
sources (default is /lib/modules/5.8.0-63-generic/build).
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - Do not compile anything before reading current logs or adjusting some configurations.

---

**Details are below.**

If you are sure what are you trying to achieve - then you have to install all necessary development tools by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

then get build-dependencies for ALSA by enabling source code repositories (*deb-src*) in `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually by using Software and Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) and execution of

```
sudo apt-get build-dep alsa-driver
```

But please note that you are trying to compile nearly the same version 1.0.25+dfsg of alsa-driver which is already available in the official repository - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/alsa-driver , you can get it by `apt-get source alsa-driver`. So after compilation you will not get any differences if you build the package with default configure options. Moreover `sudo make install` will make future system administration difficult, you should use `checkinstall` here or `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us`. Probably you will add more mess than solve real problem.

So the better way to debug is finding actual bug in already installed deb-packaged version. You really can't guess where issue is - in kernel, in ALSA, in PulseAudio and so on.